# How to use a component in another components folder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular, and wanted to have a page with the directory of `/cities/denver`. I have the file structure

```
|-- app
    |-- app.module.ts
    |-- app-routing.module.ts
      |-- [+] cities
         |-- cities.component.html
         |-- cities.component.scss
         |-- cities.component.spec.ts
         |-- cities.component.ts
         |-- [+] denver
                 |-- denver.component.html
                 |-- denver.component.scss
                 |-- denver.component.spec.ts
                 |-- denver.component.ts
```

I then declared it in `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule }      from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule }          from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeModule }  from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { AppRoutingModule }   from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent }       from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CitiesComponent }    from './cities/cities.component';
import { DenverComponent }    from './cities/denver/denver.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    CitiesComponent,
    DenverComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule }               from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }   from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent }     from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CitiesComponent }        from './cities/cities.component';
import { DenverComponent }        from './cities/denver/denver.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'cities', component: CitiesComponent },
  { path: 'cities/denver', component: DenverComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I can get to the page fine using a routerLink, but when I type it into the browser or reload it I get a 404 error saying that runtime.js, polyfill.js, etc cannot be found.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4cQb.png)

[image]

Now that I'm thinking about it, maybe cities needs to be a module? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you getting that error while running locally?

Comment: As you have different routes for cities and cities/denver, i think first you should load them lazily. All the components you have defined are eager loaded which is not a good practice and all the code will be loaded in initial bundle un-necessary even if your route is not loaded. You can learn more about lazy loading here from the official Angular documentation. https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules. 

For above issue if you can create a codesandbox or a stackblitz would be really helpful.

Comment: How do you run your app ? `ng serve` ? web server ? other ?

Comment: If you reload the page or manually enter the URL, the request is sent to the server. If the server finds no resource at `cities/runtime.js` it returns a 404. There is no resource at the requested endpoint, so you get the 404. Works as intended. What you need is to modify the server so all your frontend routes are redirected to `index.html`.

Comment: It is run by using `ng serve` locally. I'm at `localhost:4200` in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Issue sounds like it's related to how you're serving your application and not related to component folder nesting/structure.

You always need to serve index.html page with Angular routing otherwise you will be trying to pull in the server resource absolutely and not letting Angular routing take over.

Your first example with routerlink probably works because you've started the app with http://localhost:4200 and then clicked on link from there and thus not causing a server reload so you will still be within the Angular client side environment.

For example if you're serving your app via Web API you would do something like below to always force index.html to be served on a server request without changing your URL.

```
.
.
.
builder.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Path = new PathString("/index.html");
    return next();
});
.
.
.
```

Routed apps must fallback to index.html:

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback